# hot-spot wifi with wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, hot-spot

Sorry by my english

Now i live in a big house and when i go to bathroom i cant connect with my wifi, so my question is...

Can i extend the signal of my router if my laptop run like a router?? my laptop only connect with internet by wifi

```
   WIRE    -------------      WIFI    ---------------     WIFI   -------------------
----------|   ROUTER   |   ) ) ) ) )  |   LAPTOP    |  ) ) ) ) ) | me on bathroom   |
           -------------               --------------             ------------------
```

I use Android on bathroom

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a WiFi hotspot sharing wireless internet connection (single adapter)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap)

Comment: You can also look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/488588/how-do-i-connect-to-multiple-wifi-networks

Comment: What? Just out of curiosity, can you provide some use cases of a Wi-Fi connection in a bathroom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do it if your laptop has two wireless cards installed (built in or USB).
Then you can use the built in network manager to make a wireless hotspot or use the packages `hostapd` or `dnsmasq`.  For more information you can google it. If you can speak and read German you ḿay find this wiki helpful.
 http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/WLAN_Router

Comment: it can even be done with one wireless card depending on the wifi chipset

Answer (score -1):

It is probably possible to turn your laptop into a wireless hotspot using the method given in the answer to  [How do I create a WiFi hotspot sharing wireless internet connection (single adapter)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap?lq=1). It depends on the wireless hardware in your laptop. However this is complicated and not the approach I would recommend.

Instead invest in a Powerline Wi-Fi extender kit. This connects to your current router and then uses your house's mains wiring to connect to another Wi-Fi access point. My cable modem and router are in one corner of my house. After my children complained about the speed and reliability of Wi-Fi in their bedrooms I invested in a Devolo dLAN 500 Wi-Fi Powerline Starter Kit placing the Wi-Fi extender at the diagonally opposite corner of the house. It is easy to set up and rock solid.

I have had Powerline adaptors from another, cheaper, company but they were nothing like as reliable.

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: @userDepth Thank you for pointing out the broken link. I have corrected it.