# What happens when WiFi connection breaks down

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, lan

I have Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I can access internet through Wifi, Ethernet and through Bluetooth tethering.

1. Suppose I am accessing internet through Ethernet and the connection stops or I unplug the cable.  Is it the job of the kernel to check what other connections are available and try them?
2. I can see in my PC that multiple WiFi connections are handled automatically but not the multiple heterogeneous connections like WiFi, Ethernet. Is it decided at the application layer only that only one connection is to be used?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. It is not the kernel's job to do anything of the kind.  The network layer might seek an alternate route if it is configured to have a switchover default route.  See ROUTE ADD in [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples/).
2. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/488604/106063) to see if it will be possible for a single WiFi node to connect to more than one 802.11 bases.

Comment: This is a link-only answer.

Comment: @Pilot6:  Well, the second part is, but that isn't required to solve the problem in most cases.  The first part links to documentation for how to use the `ROUTE ADD` command for those not familiar with it.

Comment: The first part is also a link.