# Create a hotspot on Ubuntu 15.04 (single adapter) help!

Tags: networking, 15.04, hot-spot, hostapd

I know there are lots of questions on this type but I cannot find the answer anywhere. On Windows I can use `cmd` to create a virtual AP and share connection from a local network. However, It seems not to work the same way on Ubuntu (I'm pretty new on Ubuntu, honestly).

I had follow on these two topic :
[How do I create a WiFi hotspot sharing wireless internet connection (single adapter)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap)

and
https://seravo.fi/2014/create-wireless-access-point-hostapd
Although I've tried these many times and ask question several times but the problem seems to be unsolvable.
I would be very appreciated if anybody can help me to create a hotspot step by step. To make sure that my chipset was supported, here's my adapter information:
`Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * WDS
         * monitor
         * mesh point
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO`

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: It used to be possible on *some* device --- see http://askubuntu.com/a/488604/16395 --- but the bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/1397654 (mostly ignored) make this impossible in recent Ubuntu systems. In the bug it is stated tat the problem is fixed in 15.04 --- try to create a second device with `sudo iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan1 type ap` and then you should be able to continue as if you add two interfaces.

Comment: I tried your command and the interface was created is not `wlan1` but  `rename4`. Then I delete it and try the command again, this time a new interface was not created and it give me an error: `You need to run a management daemon, e.g. hostapd,`. Afterthat, I cannot create an AP type interface again although I give it an other name

Comment: So it seems that the bug is not really fixed... or you have some old `udev*rules` sticking around. Feel free to comment on the bug, maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 2):

This method:

1- Go to network connection (**Edit Connections**)
2- Click **Add**
3- Choose **Wi-Fi** and click **Create**
4- Type in Connection name like "**UbuntuAP**"
5- Type in SSID as you wish
6- Choose Device MAC Address from the dropdown (wlan0)
7- Wifi Security select **WPA & WPA2 Personal** and set a password.
8- Go to IPv4 Settings tab, from Method drop-down box select **Shared to other computers**.
9- Then save and close.
10- Open Terminal (**Ctrl+Alt+T**) and type in the following command with your connection name used in step 4.

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/UbuntuAP
```

11- Find `mode=infrastructure` and change it to `mode=ap`
12- Now click on WiFi icon in top right and select **Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network...**
13- Then Select **UbuntuAP** connection and click **Connect**.
14- Finish :D

Comment: sorry bro, but I just don't get your idea.  I have on only one interface that connected to the internet which is `wlan0`. This way seems not to be working on my case,  because one interface cannot just be an AP and adapter at the same time, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

*Converted from my comment to add several links that can be useful for this question*

It used to be possible on some device --- see https://askubuntu.com/a/488604/16395: you create a virtual interface with `iw` and then define a hotspot on that [with the usual methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot) and [with the usual problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453877/starting-wireless-hotspot-but-nothing-happens)...  (or with `ap-hotspot`: see on [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html)).

Unfortunately, the bug at http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/1397654 make this impossible in recent Ubuntu systems. In the bug it is stated that the problem is fixed in 15.04, although there are discordant opinions around.

Try to create a second device with `sudo iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan1 type ap`  and then you should be able to continue as if you have two physical interfaces.

If you have some specific interface the answers here: [How do I create a WiFi hotspot sharing wireless internet connection (single adapter)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap) can also help you.

Good luck!