# how to create a hotspot when my laptop is already connected to a network

Tags: wireless, 15.10, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I know a lot of people had asked this question but what I want to know is a bit different.
My laptop can access Internet by connecting to a wifi network say "qwerty".
now I want to create a hotspot (say "apple") in my ubuntu 15.10 so that I stay connected to my wifi network "qwerty" and still host a hotspot "apple" for my other devices so that both my laptop and the other device connected to my laptop could use internet.
The techniques I have discovered in this forum just allows us to create a hotspot but at the same time it disconnects the user from the existing wifi network he was originally connected to.
I want to be connected to my original wifi network and host a hotspot at the same time.... Just like "connectify"  or "my public wifi" in Windows.

So is there a way to do it???

Thanks.

Comment: This question is the same as http://askubuntu.com/questions/686564/create-a-hotspot-on-ubuntu-15-04-single-adapter-help.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this method on Ubuntu 15.10 and it works well; but I am not sure about older versions.

Step 1:Download kde-nm-connection-editor (Plasma-nm) from Ubuntu Software center.

[image]

Step 2: Open Terminal and type :

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/kde5-nm-connection-editor.desktop
```

Then comment the line containing NoDisplay=true by adding # before it.

Step 3: Now search and open kde5-nm-connection-editor

[image]

Step 4: Now go to Connections >> add >> Wi-Fi(shared)

[image]

Modify Connection name and SSID according to you
Step 5: Move to Wi-Fi Security and choose WPA & WPA2 Personal and set the password.

[image]

Then Select OK and you are done.
Step 6: To start the hotspot go to Wi-Fi Settings

[image]

Then click on Connect to Hidden Network

[image]

Choose the network you just created from drop down list and click on Connect

[image]

Now you are done.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

follow this link that help you to use your laptop as a hotspot : http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. **;-)**